# Pull only latest changes from SVN -Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, jenkins-cli

I am working with Jenkins CI and I have connected my SVN repository to get the files on build. 
I am facing two issues here.

1. I need only the changed files -not the whole set of files.
2. I don't need all the project files but only the files which needed to deploy (code files should be excluded). My .pubxml have
   the parameters to exclude it. But while fetching from SVN jenkin
   pulls all the files and Jenkins FTP plugin can points only to the
   workspace. I need to upload only the files which needed for the
   release. Jenkins workspace contains all the files which I have in
   SVN. Is there any option to restrict this?

Comment: You want to monitor only certain set of files?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to have a powershell or batch script at some point to determine what files you need to throw out. I would suggest pulling everything down and throwing out files you do not need. You can determine such files by running some magic with the SVN command line utility. Go through that documentation to see how you can run a diff to receive a list of changed files.

Comment: Thanks. How Can I access the SVN Command line utility from Poweshell?

Comment: If you are using something like TortoiseSVN it should have the option to install with command line utility. Search in the install directories and if it's not in there you might try running the installer with the command line utilities checked. I can't remember if it automatically adds it into your environment path or not but I would add the folder it resides in so you can simply call it by typing "svn" to invoke the program.